# Creating computer objects without accessing ARS console

Tags: powershell

I want to create computer objects without accessing the ARS console

```
powershell.exe -command New-QADComputer -Name <Name of the new computer> -ParentContainer "<OU-Copied the distinguishedName of an earlier computer object from the AD>" -ObjectAttributes @{edsajoincomputertodomain='domain\userID'}
```

*I am getting the below error while executing the above command.*

```
New-QADComputer : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'ActiveRoles.ManagementShell.Data.IdentityParameter'
required by parameter 'ParentContainer'. Specified method is not supported.
At line:1 char:49
+ ... ntContainer <OU> ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [New-QADComputer], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgument,ActiveRoles.ManagementShell.Powershell.Cmdlets.NewComputerCmdlet
```

**Note:** We need to use the same credential which we used to add the computer object in AD to join the client computer to Domain.

Comment: I have removed the [[tag:batch-file]] tag from your question, as the console used to interact with powershell is irrelevant to your issue.

Comment: Looks like you either forgot `"` quotes around the OU DN, or have a trailing , after it

Comment: `powershell.exe -command New-QADComputer -Name <Name of the new computer> -ParentContainer "OU" -ObjectAttributes @{edsajoincomputertodomain='domain\userID'}` but same error